# Multiple powerdns with 1 mysql

Tags: powerdns

If I connect 6 or more master powerdns server with a single high availability load balancing MySQL database, 
any performance issue? or is that a wrong way to configure powerdns?

or Do I have to add 6 add separate database for each and have to make master slave?

Comment: I have no idea if using a shared database cluster will affect performance in your case, because I have no idea what you're trying to do with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most people create multiple DNS servers for redundancy and performance. So creating a single point of failure  by setting up your infrastructure with only a single MYSQL server seems less than optimal...

Typically people use MYSQL replication to achieve a Highly Available backend

Comment: what if that database is HA load balancing? i want to know that will 6 power dns server run/support properly with single database? or is that wrong to configure powerdns?

Comment: If your database can handle the number of queries there is a priori nothing wrong with using a single database